# How to join 2 json objects in Express

Tags: json, node.js, express

The following code is working while running in javascript env. But doesn't work when I do the same thing in Express. Any help will be appreciated.

```
function joinJson(dest,src){
    for(var key in src){
        dest[key] = src[key];
    }
    return dest;
}

j = {currentTime : "time"};

router.get('/:id',(req,res) => {
    Timer.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(timer => {
        res.send(joinJson(timer,j));
    })
    .catch(err =>  res.status(404))
});
```

Is there any inbuilt function to join two JSON objects?

Comment: the return of `findById` should be an array with one object inside (unless multiple id's match somehow), also, your code doesnt make sense. you get the data from mongodb then change the values as you send it?

Comment: I want to send some extra information with the results I am getting from MongoDB

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to merge keys in the two objects

```js
const object1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};

const object2 = {
 d: 4,
 e: 5
}

const object3 = Object.assign(object1, object2);

console.log( object3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use spread syntax in ES6

```js
const timer = {
  id: 1
}
const j = { currentTime: 'time' };
const union = {...timer, ...j};

console.log(union);
```

so in your code, it will become

```
j = {currentTime : "time"};

router.get('/:id',(req,res) => {
    Timer.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(timer => {
        res.send({
          ...timer,
          ...j
        });
    })
    .catch(err =>  res.status(404))
});
```

Hope it helps